# Selecting the Correct Display Item Field when Adjusting Fonts in SSMS 2017

Tags: ssms

I am trying to use adjust the font color in SSMS 2017 and 
it's hard to find which Display Items certain symbols fall under.

1)  Where do T-SQL commas fall under?

2)  How can I find out?  Is there a list somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Commas come under 'SQL Operator', but apply also to parenthesis (), asterisk * and periods . (and likely more including but not limited to !, %, ^)

[image]

Comment: You're right!  Is there a list or table that shows what is covered under each Display Item?

Comment: This is probably as close as you'll get without trawling through MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173443(v=sql.120).aspx